# bootstrap two col-sm but two row for xs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm new in Twitter Bootstrap (v3). As i said in the title, I want to design two columns, when the screen is SM and larger, I want it show two columns but when it's smaller screen (XS), I want it show two rows instead. How can I do it?

SM and Larger:

[---------][---------]

XS:

[---------]

[---------]

Comment: What you describe is the default behaviour for columns in BS3. What do your columns do at XS? They should stack and be 100% width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p>Hey, I am column 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p>Hiya, I am column 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `col-sm` class will mean that the columns will be in-line for sm width and larger, then when stepping under sm (xs) the columns will stack on top of each other.

Hope it helps!